# iOS Cloudkit fetchRecordWithID is not returning a response

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

This case is happening on only one particular test device (xs-max). The other devices we could not replicate this.

The completion block for fetchRecordWithID isn't executing no matter how long I wait.

Here is the code I call on tap of button.

```
//recordID is not nil

[[[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase]fetchRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (record) {
            //save record
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }

    }];
```

I couldn't debug this as the execution never reaches the block.

Any case this might happen ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the case, but the device iCloud settings are not loaded properly.

We had to restart the device which prompted to re-validate the apple ID in the settings.

Once the validation is done, the icloud settings are shown as expected. And there after, the code executed as expected.

Adding screenshot for reference.

[image]